# Add class when button clicked in react.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I've been working on React for a few weeks now, and while I've got most of the basic syntax down (props, states), I'm struggling to draw some connections with some concepts, most notably adding classes when a state has changed. I'm trying to build a simon says game, which contains four buttons, all built using a Button component. These are initially set to have a opacity of .3 and an active state of false. When clicked, the state "active" becomes true, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to add a css class that can give the button a full opacity. Here is my code:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      active: false
    }
  }
  handleClick(){
    this.setState({active: !this.state.active})
  }
  renderButtons(i, f){
    return <Button value={i} className="button" id={f} active= {this.state.active} onClick={() => this.handleClick()}/>
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.renderButtons("red", "buttonRed")}
        {this.renderButtons("blue", "buttonBlue")}
        {this.renderButtons("green", "buttonGreen")}
        {this.renderButtons("yellow", "buttonYellow")}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And my css:

```
.button{
  width: 100px;
  height: 45px;
  opacity: .3;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#buttonRed{
  background: red;
}
#buttonBlue{
  background: blue;
}
#buttonGreen{
  background: green;
}
#buttonYellow{
  background: yellow;
}
```

So, at this moment, I would simply like to add a class when clicking the button while still keeping the "button" class to the component. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

React has a couple of ways of doing this. The first is as suggested by Tudor Ilisoi, which is simply concatenating strings.
The second way is to give `className` an `Object` instead of a `string`. This way is arguably simpler but requires you to add the `classnames` module.
You can install it with either `npm install --save classnames` or `yarn add classnames`.
You can import it with:

```
import classNames from 'classnames';
```

And then you can use it in the following way:

```
<button className={classNames({button: true, active: this.state.active})} />
```

The first pair of curly brackets just tells react that we are passing a dynamic property, and the second is just the normal JavaScript syntax for objects.
Note that the object is wrapped by the `classNames()` function.
If we had declared it earlier, we could just as easily do:

```
render(){
    const classes = classNames({
        button: true, // we always want this class
        active: this.state.active, // only add this class if the state says so
     });

     return (
          <button className={classes} />
     );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a very thorough explanation! I'm assuming you can pass as many key/value pairs into the className object as you want? And just so I'm understanding correctly, Button will have one class of 'button' when this.state.active is false, but two classes 'button' and 'active' when this.state.active is true?

Comment: What if the classes have hyphens?  I'm not allowed to do `{red-button: true}`.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I have hard time getting this to work with any class name:

`const valueSpan = <span className={{small: true}}>label</span>;`

renders as `<span class="[object Object]">label</span>`

Comment: I think I'm missing something simple here. I tried both variants of your solution, but it fails, and in chrome inspector it appears as this: `<button class="[object Object]">`

Comment: @steve, I have edited the answer. You should be able to see it online in a while, just after the peer review. Hope it helps, cheers!

Comment: @steve it's online

Comment: Thanks @AlbertoSchiabel. Importing classNames is what I ended up doing. Was looking for a way to do it without adding an additional dependency, but I guess it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

if you are looking for 2021/2022 answer:
Here is an example that uses react hooks, which add the class name app to a div element when we click on a Toggle class button.

```
 import React, { useState } from "react";import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [isActive, setActive] = useState("false");
  const handleToggle = () => {
    setActive(!isActive);  };
  return (
    <div className={isActive ? "app" : null}>
       <h1>Hello react</h1>
       <button onClick={handleToggle}>Toggle class</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30439286)

Answer (score 1):

change `className="button"` to `className={'button ' + f}`

The expression enclosed in curly braces is evaluated as javascript and it produces a string

Also note that when using the curly brace syntax you do not have to add double quotes `""` around attribute value .

When your JSX is parsed, React will generate the proper HTML attribute, for example `class="button red"`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried, pass an optional parameter to renderButtons, check it and add to class :

```
...
 renderButtons(i, f, c){
    var cssClass =  c&&c!=""? "button " + c : "button";   
    return <Button value={i} className={cssClass}  id={f} active= {this.state.active} onClick={() => this.handleClick()}/>
  }
...
```